# JS Как хранить данные в объекте на каждый момент времени

Tags: javascript, electron

У меня есть данные такого типа

```js
let data = {
  'myProject' : {
    'index.html' : {
      workTime: 1234,
      freeTime: 324,
      keys: 460
    },
    'index.js' : {
      workTime: 6444,
      freeTime: 345
      keys: 4029
    }
  }
}
```

Эти данные обновляются каждую секунду. И мне нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было доставать эти данные по дате. Например, 31 декабря workTime = 7890, а 1 января workTime = 120.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать у каждого экземпляра этих данных числовой ключ - timestamp в секундах (как `Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)`). И потом перебором находить этот объект по его ключу согласно требуемому времени или например от полночи начала нужного дня до полночи его завершения минус секунда. Где это всё хранить уже другой вопрос, например в json при выходе из приложения, и загружать при старте.

Что-то вроде этого:

```js
let data = {
  'myProject': {
    'index.html': [
      {
        timestamp: 1608753541,
        workTime: 1234,
        freeTime: 324,
        keys: 460
      },
      {
        timestamp: 1608753542,
        workTime: 1235,
        freeTime: 323,
        keys: 459
      }
    ],
    'index.js': [
      {
        timestamp: 1608753541,
        workTime: 6444,
        freeTime: 345,
        keys: 4029
      },
      {
        timestamp: 1608753542,
        workTime: 6444,
        freeTime: 345,
        keys: 4029
      },
      {
        timestamp: 1608753543,
        workTime: 6444,
        freeTime: 345,
        keys: 4029
      }
    ]
  }
}

function getOneDataItem( pageName, timestamp ){
  return data.myProject[pageName].find( item => item.timestamp === timestamp );
};

console.log( getOneDataItem( 'index.html', 1608753542 ) );
```

Comment: Ну понимаете, данные обновляются каждую секунду, тогда получится очень много лишних данных, нужно чтобы данные хранились просто по дням и за один месяц, то есть для каждого файла будет от 1 до 30 объектов, описывающих дни.

Comment: Вы можете уже имеющийся объект обновлять. И ставить ему timestamp начала дня (полночь), и соответственно искать его по началу дня. А если наступает следующий день, то заводить новый объект и работать уже с ним. То же самое можно на любые промежутки сделать - неделю, месяц. Просто начало в штампе указывать.